# Django Model design for a basic inventory application

Tags: django

I am new to Django (and databases for that matter) and trying to create a simple inventory application to help learn. I've been through the tutorials and am going through some books, but I am stuck at what i think is simple, just not sure where to look or how to ask.

With an inventory application, you have your equipment which then has a manufacturer, which the equipment has a model number that only that manufacturer has. Lets say Dell Optiplex 3040. I am also using the admin console right now as well. So i would like to be able to relate equipment to a manufacturer and then also relate the equipment to the model number. It almost seems as I am needing to use the many to many field and the through field to accomplish what I am trying to do but I dont think that is the right way to do it (shown in the link below). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Below is the code I have so far. Thank you.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.



class Department(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.department

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer

class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
    equipmentModel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.equipmentModel




class Employees(models.Model):
    employee_name_first = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employee_name_last = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employee_username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone =  models.IntegerField()
    assigned_equipment = models.ForeignKey('Device', default='undefined')
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='undefined')
    job_title = models.ManyToManyField('Job_Positions', default='undefined')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_username

class Device(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',unpack_ipv4=False,null=True, blank=True)#might be good to seperate IP in its own class because a device can have multiple IP's
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial_number


class Job_Positions(models.Model):
    position_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return position_title
```

***Edit to add the updated code and the admin.py code in response question I had to answer.

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.


from .models import Device,Department,Manufacturer,Employees, Job_Positions, EquipmentModel

class DeviceModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["ip", "department","model","serial_number","date_updated"]
    list_filter = ["department","model","ip"]
    search_fields = ["ip"]
    class Meta:
        model = Device


class EmployeesModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["employee_name_first", "employee_name_last", "employee_username", "phone"]
    list_filter = ["department"]
    class Meta:
        model = Employees


admin.site.register(Device, DeviceModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Department)
admin.site.register(Manufacturer)
admin.site.register(EquipmentModel)
admin.site.register(Employees, EmployeesModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Job_Positions)
```

updated models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.



class Department(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.department

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer

class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_number




class Employees(models.Model):
    employee_name_first = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employee_name_last = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employee_username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone =  models.IntegerField()
    assigned_equipment = models.ForeignKey('Device', default='undefined')
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='undefined')
    job_title = models.ManyToManyField('Job_Positions', default='undefined')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_username

class Device(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',unpack_ipv4=False,null=True, blank=True)#might be good to seperate IP in its own class because a device can have multiple IP's
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.ForeignKey('EquipmentModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial_number


class Job_Positions(models.Model):
    position_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return position_title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship is not what you want here, because any piece of equipment (I assume) can only have one manufacturer.

You do need an intermediate model which stores the model information, and you already have one in your `EquipmentModel`. I would suggest modifying it as follows:

```
class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
    # This stores information about a particular model of device
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And then instead of having a foreign key to the manufacturer in `Device`, replace it with a foreign key to the equipment model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
   # ...
   model = models.ForeignKey('EquipmentModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: That makes sense, however it doesn't have the exact effect that i was looking I think (at least in the admin site). This might be a front end thing that has to be done, but is there a way to make the model list depend on the manufacturer inside admin? Say i have Dell, HP, IBM ect, and have many models under each of them, is there a way to limit the models that show in a dropdown to the list of manufactures? I will update the code for the admin site I have in the main post.

Comment: You would need to modify Django's admin templates to achieve that. However if all you want is to be able to easily pick out models by manufacturer, you can just change the `__str__` method on the `EquipmentModel` to return something like `'{} - {}'.format(self.manufacturer.manufacturer, self.model_number)`, and change default ordering to be by manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the easy way to do that. I did notice you had self.manufacturer.manufacturer. Why do you have two manufacturer? would that point to the class instead of the foreignkey inside the equipment model class? If that does point to the class, shouldn't the first manufacturer need to be capitalized like Manufacturer.manufacturer? Both appear to work when setting is as self.manufacturer and self.manufacturer.manufacturer. Just not sure why, thank you for the help!

Comment: Self is EquipmentModel, which has a manufacturer field. So self.manufacturer is the Manufacturer. Your Manufacturer class has a manufacturer field that stores its name. Hence self.manufacturer.manufacturer. It would be better to change the field on your Manufacturer class to something more descriptive like "name" so that you end up with self.manufacturer.name which is easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but is there a reason to use the class Manufacturer instead of the foreign key inside EquipmentModel when using the __str__ method? Example, self.manufacturer versus self.manufacturer.manufacturer? Both appear to return the same results to me. Thanks again

Comment: That works too because your `Manufacturer` has a `__str__` method itself, which is what gets used in the case of `self.manufacturer`. Either is fine. I was just being more explicit.